# open popup inside popup jquery mobile

Tags: jsp, jquery-mobile, popup

I have two popup I want to open another popup form first pop up I have used the normal link, but it is not working and I looked at some tutorials but I don't understand this is my two pop up

```
<div data-role="popup" id="classMenu<%=result.get(i)%>">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;">

                 //link to another popup

          <li>   <a href="option<%=result.get(i) %>" data-rel="popup">Delete</a>         </li>
            <li><a href="showDataProperty.jsp">DataType Property</a></li>
        </ul></div>
```

I want to open below popup from the above popup this is my second popup

```
<div data-role="popup" id="option<%=result.get(i) %>" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="b">
                <h3>Delete?</h3>
</div>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div data-role="popup" id="classMenu<%=result.get(i)%>">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;">

                 //link to another popup

          <li>   <a href="option<%=result.get(i) %>" data-rel="popup">Delete</a>         </li>
            <li><a href="showDataProperty.jsp" >DataType Property</a></li>
           <li> <a href="#popupDelete" data-rel="popup" data-inline="true" data-position-to="window">popup2</a></li>
        </ul></div>



    <div data-role="popup" id="popupDelete" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="b">
                <h3>Delete?</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this one, it's not working I think I have to close first one before but I don't know how because I'm beginner in jquery mobile

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the popup documentation (http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/), you will see that as of version 1.4.x of jQM it does not support chained popups:

> The framework does not currently support chaining of popups so it's not possible to embed a link from one popup to another popup. All links with a data-rel="popup" inside a popup will not do anything at all.

There is a workaround in the DOCs that opens the second popup after closing the first one.

In order to have one popup above another, you will need to use a different popup plugin. Fortunately the **[SimpleDialog2](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/index.html)** plugin for jQM does support chained popups. Here is a blog I wrote describing how to achieve chained popups with SimpleDialog2:

http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/chained-popups-with-simpledialog2/